# operator over loading: "operator+"must take either zero or one argument

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have a matrix class called IntMatrix

```
namespace mtm
{
    class IntMatrix
    {
    private:
        int** data;
        int col;
        int row;
    public:
          IntMatrix(int row,int col,int num=0);
         IntMatrix(const IntMatrix& mat);
          //some functions
          IntMatrix ::operator+(int num) const;
          friend IntMatrix operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix);
};
//ctor
IntMatrix::IntMatrix(int row,int col, int num) :data(new int*[row]), col(col), row(row)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            data[i] = new int[col];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col); j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = num;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to overload operator+, so that this  would work:

```
//copy ctor
IntMatrix::IntMatrix(const IntMatrix& mat)
{
    data=new int*[mat.row];
    for(int i = 0; i < mat.row; i++) 
    {
        data[i]=new int[mat.col];
    }
    row=mat.row;
    col=mat.col;
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
     for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
     {
         data[i][j]=mat.data[i][j];
     }
    }
}

IntMatrix IntMatrix::operator+(int num) const
{
    IntMatrix new_Matrix(*this);
    for(int i=0;i<new_Matrix.row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<new_Matrix.col;j++)
        {
            new_Matrix.data[i][j]+=num;
        }
    }
    return new_Matrix;
}
// the function I have problem with:
IntMatrix IntMatrix::operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix) 
{
    return matrix+num;
}

int main()
{
 mtm::IntMatrix mat(2,1,3);
 mtm::IntMatrix mat2=2+mat;
return 0;
}
```

how ever no matter what I do I keep getting this error:
error: ‘mtm::IntMatrix mtm::IntMatrix::operator+(const int&, const mtm::IntMatrix&)’ must take either zero or one argument
IntMatrix IntMatrix::operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix)

I tried:

```
friend IntMatrix operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix);
IntMatrix operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix);
IntMatrix operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix)const;
IntMatrix operator+(int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix);
IntMatrix operator+( int num, const IntMatrix& matrix);
```

yet I got the same error with all of them, so does any one know what is the correct way to write it?

Comment: @molbdnilo this is a reproducible example, I posted the class, the ctor, the function I have problem with , and the main()

Comment: Are you sure that you get that error from the code you posted?

Comment: Your current example (with `friend`) compiles just right for me, provided that I add a body for that function (and fix typo in constructor)

Comment: ok I will add the body to that function

Comment: you posted enough to compile it, but it doesnt reproduce the error: https://godbolt.org/z/Lqd5xL

Comment: you declare a non-member free function as friend (for which I would not expect that error) and there is no definition for it. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @raghad This has a syntax error and no `operator+`. Fixing those, and the indexing bug in the constructor, [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/242f54bb3e629cb8). Please compile your "[mcve]" first to make sure that it's wrong in the way you think.

Comment: this confusion aside, you seem to not be aware of the difference between a member and non-member friend function. In the code you posted, `operator+` is declared as non-member friend function and the number of parameters should be just fine. I suppose you forgot to make a clean build when compiling

Comment: @Yksisarvinen what's the typo in the constructor?

Comment: @raghad `for (int j = 0; j < col); j++)` - one extra `)` here.

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a function with `friend` does ***not*** make it part of the class. The int+IntMatrix operator is *not* `IntMatrix::operator+` - it's just `operator+`.

```
//        wrong - delete this part
//        vvvvvvvvvvv
IntMatrix IntMatrix::operator+(const int &num, const IntMatrix& matrix) 
{
    return matrix+num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not aware what do you define for adding a escalar to a matrix but imagine for a while something like

```
IntMatrix IntMatrix::operator+(int k) const
{    
    IntMatrix temp(this->x+k, this->y+k, this->z+k);
    return temp;
}
```

so having a vector foo `[0,1,2]`
you can do:

```
IntMatrix r = foo + 2;
```

and r will be `[2,3,4]`